# Drupal 8 How to Set HTML required in select list client side

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have created a list (Text) type field in content type and make it required, but it is validating server side, not client side (HTML 5 validation).

Basically I need to add "required" attribute in SELECT tag.

See below screen:
[image]

Similar to this [W3shools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required)

Answer (score -1):

Please add required attribute to the field by adding an alter function in themename.theme file.

```
function themename_formname_alter($form,$form_state,$form_id){
   $form['field_name'] = [
      '#required' => true
   ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but It will validate serve side not client side.

Answer (score -1):

In the field settings you will find default value option where you need to put your key which you want to show as default into it.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response but without setting up the default value we need to validate (client site) the field. See screenshot in question for reference.